# How to interpret the "Formal syntax" of CSS found on MDN

Tags: css

I came across a CSS `background` property which has the following value:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #F8F8F8;
```

The syntax of the `background` property is given at [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), like this:

```
Formal syntax: [ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>
               where <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box>
               and <final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box> || <background-color>
```

Does the order of the values of the `background` property matter? And, more generally: how to interpret this "**Formal syntax**" provided on the MDN.

Answer (score 9):

The formal syntax is [documented at the MDN site itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax). The "more general" question you have is probably too broad for Stack Overflow: just go through the documentation and come back if you have any specific questions.

One such specific question you have is whether the order of the values for the `background` property matters. Most parts of the background (of specifically a bg-layer) are separated by "double bars", which require **no specific order** according to the MDN('s formal syntax). To quote the [specific documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#Double_bar) on double bars:

> **Double bar**
>
> Separating two or more components by a double bar, ||, means that all entities are options: **at least one of them must be present, and they may appear in any order**. Typically this is used to define the different values of a shorthand property.

As a footnote, though I love and use MDN all the time, a probably more *authorative* source would be W3.org, where you can find for example the [background shorthand syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) as well as an explanation of the syntax in [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/). It basically says the same, e.g. about "double bars":

> A double bar (||) separates two or more options: one or more of them must occur, in any order.

This works in practice for the `background` property, as you can see in this snippet where regardless of order the properties are parsed the same:

```css
#a { background: 100% / 2% url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvUr4.png') red repeat-x; }
#b { background: red repeat-x url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvUr4.png') 100% / 2%; }
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<br />
<div id="b">B</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Order does not matter. But, order *does* matter.

**tl;dr;**

Order doesn't matter, it's what it is, in that documentation on MDN and is also corroborated by the W3C Specs. I will repeat that part verbatim:

> A double bar (`||`) separates two or more options: one or more of them
>   must occur, in any order.

*But don't jump to that conclusion yet!*

Order ***does*** matter. Let's take your example of `background` shorthand syntax:

```
[ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>
where <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box>
and <final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box> || <background-color>
```

And, because it lists syntax of all possible properties for multiple backgrounds, let's reduce the complexity by picking one background. It looks like this:

```
<bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box> || <background-color>
```

Working this out in a code snippet and relating with the documentation referred in your question and the other answer, you might believe that all these properties which are separated by a double-bar (`||`) can be omitted and can occur in any order. **Right**?

### Wrong.

While MDN is a good reference, it isn't complete and can omit important details sometimes. In this particular case, both these references...

1. *MDN ref here*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background
2. *W3C ref here*: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

...state the same syntax and explain all properties, *but* leave out one detail.

Now look closely at the property called `box`. There are two `box` properties separated by double-bar (`||`). That should mean that you can either omit `box` or specify `box` in any order. *But, that is not entirely correct*. While you may of course omit `box` altogether from the shorthand, you cannot put them in any order you wish without getting unintended results. *This is not stated in the MDN reference on `background` linked above*.

But, in another reference on `background-clip` by same MDN here:

3. *MDN ref*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

It states:

> Canonical order: the unique non-ambiguous order defined by the formal grammar

Which means, the order is governed by ambiguity of the properties. If the properties are non-ambiguous, then the order or omission doesn't matter. If the properties are ambiguous, then the order and/or omission does matter.

In your `background` shorthand example, the two `box` properties (when present) are interpreted as the first one being `background-origin` and the second one being `background-clip`.

If you read another source of documentation here:

4. *Opera dev ref*: https://dev.opera.com/articles/css3-borders-backgrounds-boxes/

It states:

> There are a few things to be aware of when using the new background
>   shorthand. If only one box value is specified both background-clip and
>   background-origin are set to this value. If two are specified then the
>   first is used for the origin and the second is used for the clip.

5. And W3c ref here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-origin

States this:

> Note that if ‘background-clip’ is ‘padding-box’, ‘background-origin’
>   is ‘border-box’, ‘background-position’ is ‘top left’ (the initial
>   value), and the element has a non-zero border, then the top and left
>   of the background image will be clipped.

So, if you omit one of the values, it will be interpreted as both `background-origin` and `background-clip`. But, if you provide both the values then the order is important, otherwise you will get weird results. Not only this, the behaviour is influenced by another property of `background-position`.

This can be easily demonstrated using this example in the snippet below. In the first `div` the background-image is positioned 15px from the padding but continues across the border. Notice that the first `box` value is `padding-box` and the second one is `border-box`. In the second `div` the background-image is position 15px from the border but stops where the padding ends. Notice here that the first value is `border-box` and second value is `padding-box`. In the third `div`, the background-image starts from the border and continues across the border. In this case one value is omitted and both `background-origin` and `background-clip` get the value of `border-box`.

***Snippet:***

```css
div { width: 120px; height: 120px; display: inline-block; }
#r {
    border: 15px #f00;
    border-style: dotted dashed dashed dotted;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/150) no-repeat 15px 15px padding-box border-box;
}
#g {
    border: 15px #0f0;
    border-style: dotted dashed dashed dotted;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/150) no-repeat 15px 15px border-box padding-box;
}
#b {
    border: 15px #00f;
    border-style: dotted dashed dashed dotted;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/150) no-repeat 15px 15px border-box ;
}
```

```html
<div id="r">Red</div>
<div id="g">Green</div>
<div id="b">Blue</div>
```

### Bottomline:

It is good to refer to the documentation. But, it is even better to consult multiple sources. *This answer refers to 5 sources*. Read the W3C specs, but not just at one place, read all related property references to see how one property can be affected by other property values, and even order. And do not forget to try out a sample, you might never know a surprise could be waiting for you!

.